# Android Studio can't cant find library dependency 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.7.0'

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, dependencies, mapbox

For some reason when my android studio fails to find this SDK here is the Build log:

```
Failed to resolve: com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.7.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

Here is the Project build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                username = 'mapbox'
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is Module build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mapboxtest"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.7.0'){
        exclude group: 'group_name', module: 'module_name'
    }
}
```

I'm very new this type of stuff so therefore if the problem is right in front of my face please tell me what it is.

Comment: Try removing exclude group: 'group_name', module: 'module_name' line...

it will take group name & module name value.. not this string..

Comment: did you  ever solve it?

Comment: @KashifMehmood No

Comment: @KishanMaurya Tried that already

Comment: @KashifMehmood Check out the latest answer by me that's all I figured out and it works

Comment: Strangely enough, a couple of years later, I found exactly the same problem when trying to use mapbox's sdk 10 for Android. Followed their instructions exactly, but couldn't make it work. I ended up searching maven central for MapBox SDK and used the latest version they had (9.2.1). Simply select the version you want, navigate to the Gradle(short) tab, and paste that into your dependencies: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-sdk

Answer (score 0):

So I still haven't figured it out completely still unsure why it cant resolve
`com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.7.0`

 But I did a little bit of research tried out other versions and found one that works which is this one:
`com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.2.1`

 But this one works just fine app compiles all references resolved etc. But if you figure anything out about why:
`com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.7.0` 
 Doesn't but if you figure it out definitely let me know Thanks!